# ARM Cortex M3 Bootloader with User code at normal 0 address?

Tags: arm, bootloader, cortex-m

I have been researching ARM M3 bootloaders and most seem to work with the bootloader code sitting in low memory and the user code in higher memory.  This requires the users application to be linked differently when used with the bootloader.  That is some address above the bootloader code which is located at 0x00000000.  I think this an inconvenience.

I would like to know if it is possible to have a bootloader which is located in high memory and yet still allow the users application to be linked normally so it starts at 0x00000000 in low memory ?

I have done this before with PIC bootloaders which also have reset & stack code at 0x0000 similar to ARM M3's NVIC table.

They way this has worked form me on the PIC is that bootloader is located in the top 1k of the flash.  Reset vector and SP code which is at 0x0000 points to the start address of the bootloader code. Thus the bootloader starts after reset.

Now when the bootloaders is downloading the user code it puts it into low memory where the linker thinks it should go, the only exception being it does not allow overwriting of its own reset and SP vectors located at 0x0000.  Instead it 'catches' these and stores them in flash within its high memory.

When the bootloader is ready for the users code to start it retrieves the initial reset and SP vectors it stored during the download and starts the user code using these.

At the next reset the bootloader will start and it can do a check to see if it should wait for a new user program or just start the users code using the vectors it has stored.

Could the above method be translated for use on the ARM M3  ?

Comment: Another side effect of doing this that hasn't been mentioned below - you will bypass your bootloader vector table modification scheme if you flash your user code with any other tool (debugger). You'll then need to flash your bootloader back on to fix the vector table, and upload the user code to the bootloader. This will be way more inconvenient than a one time modification of your start address.

Answer (score 3):

I think the expression 'go with the flow' applies here. You are trying to do something that the ARM is not intended to do so I think you are making unnecessary problems for yourself. Putting the app above the bootloader just requires linking at a different address then setting the VTOR register to that address.

Comment: One of the two applications has to be linked to higher memory, either the user app or the bootloader.  I simply suggest moving the bootloader which would be done just once rather than having to trouble the user to move every app to a special address.

Comment: Where is the reference that says the ARM is not designed to do this? One of the two applications has to be linked to higher memory, either the user app or the bootloader.  I simply suggest moving the bootloader which would be done just once rather than having to trouble the user to move every app to a special address.  Setting VTOR would be required on entry to the bootloader in high memory and again prior to starting the user app located at 0x0.

Comment: I think you are proposing that your application reflashes the vectors at 0x0. When you power cycle, your app, starting after the vectors at 0x0 will run but the bootloader will never run until you reflash the start vector.

Comment: No.  SP & PC vectors at 0x0 (8 bytes)would always point to the bootloader in high memory and would not change. All the app vectors would be load at 0x0 as usual with the exception of the SP & PC vectors.  Then during the downloading of the user app the first 8 bytes (SP & PC) would not be put at 0x0 but put in high memory instead.  when the bootloader wants to start the app it uses the SP & PC vectors it has kept in high memory during the download.

Comment: I prefer to have the bootloader and whatever it needs to run be entirely independent of any loaded application. By loading vectors with the app that point at the bootloader you are relying on the app behaving to be able to run the bootloader. For me, the bootloader is unmutable and it doesn't matter what the app does, the bootloader can always run and load a new app. Anyway, good luck with your scheme.